# Using Unity Texture in native Direct3D 11 DLL - DEVICE_OPEN_SHARED_RESOURCE_INVALIDARG_RETURN

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, directx, directx-11

I have a DX11 Unity application, which is loading a native C++ DLL. The DLL creates its own D3D11 Device. I would like to take a texture from Unity and use it in my C++ DLL - ideally without copying to CPU memory.

On Unity side I do this :

```
MyNativeLib.SetBuffers11(srcTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());
```

In this case, srcTexture is RenderTexture.
In the native DLL, I do this:

```
void SetBuffers11(ID3D11Resource* colorRes)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    ID3D11Texture2D* tempColor;
    colorRes->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&tempColor);
    tempColor->GetDesc(&texDesc); //This works

    ID3D11Resource* tempResource;
    HRESULT openResult = m_device->OpenSharedResource1(
        colorRes, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)&tempResource); //This fails
    tempResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)(&tempColor));
    tempColor->GetDesc(&texDesc);
}
```

If I just query texture description, I get correct D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC. But when I try to access the texture data, I get `MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #18: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER`. So I tried to use OpenSharedResource - It also failed but it told me, the pointer is probably NT (I am not actualy sure about that) and I should OpenSharedResource1. So I did and I get this :

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource1: 
Returning E_INVALIDARG, meaning invalid parameters were passed. 
[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #381: DEVICE_OPEN_SHARED_RESOURCE_INVALIDARG_RETURN]
```

OpenSharedResource1 returns E_INVALIDARG and pointer is set to 0. I am not sure which function to call for textures created by Unity in DX11 mode.

When I query for texture description, I get this:

```
Format : 0x09 (DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_TYPELESS)
Bind Flags : 0x20 | 0x08 (D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE and D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET)
CPU ACCESS : 0
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: `colorRes->GetDesc(&texDesc); //This works` - this can not work because `ID3D11Resource` has no `GetDesc` method.

Comment: @user7860670 that was a type I made while minifying example. Post edited, question still stands

Comment: Edited code should not work either, because `(ID3D11Texture2D*)colorRes;` cast is invalid. The only proper way to obtain a pointer to derived class interface is to use `QueryInterface`. You also write *"when I try to access the texture data"* but i don't see any code like this in the question and assuming that texture description is correct texture data can not be accessed from the CPU.

Comment: I fixed the cast, however the sample is still broken and throws the same errors. I know I cannot access texture data directly from CPU and the sample is not doing it, i dont know why you mention it.

Comment: Alright, so you are trying to `OpenSharedResource1`, but was the resource actually created as a shared resource (with `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` or similar flag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly managed to get this working. I had several issues with my original approach.

To share a texture between two DX11 devices, the texture needs to have both [D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_resource_misc_flag) and [D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_resource_misc_flag) set for MiscFlags. This a recommended approach since Windows 8. There are also some other restrictions when creating shareable texture, check the docs.

As far as I know, Unity wont let me specify these flags (maybe in a native plugin), but I can capture the original DX11 device, create a new shareable texture and copy the Unity texture to this new texture on the original Unity DX11 device.

```
    ID3D11Device* otherDevice;
    ID3D11Device1* otherDevice1;
    unityTexture->GetDevice(&otherDevice);
    otherDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof (ID3D11Device1), (void**)&otherDevice1);
    otherDevice->Release();// throw away the original device
    otherDevice1->GetImmediateContext1(&otherContext);
    //you can now create the shareable texture on otherContext
```

Notice that `ID3D11Device1` is needed, since it contains methods for working with shared resources.

Now that you have shareable texture, you first need to share it on the original device, by creating a shared handle from the shareable texture :

```cpp
IDXGIResource1* shareableResource;
//sharedTexture is the resource you want to share
sharedTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource1),(void**)&shareableResource);
    
HANDLE sharedHandle;
HRESULT createSharedRes = shareableResource->CreateSharedHandle(NULL,
                        DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ,//other device will only READ
                        nullptr,
                        &sharedHandle);
shareableResource->Release();
```

This shared handle can now be passed to other DX11 device, which can open it :

```cpp
m_device->OpenSharedResource1(sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)sharedTextureLocal);
```

Now `sharedTextureLocal` contains a pointer to a ID3D11Texture2D on your local device, which you can use. However, when you want do move texture data from one device to another, you need to synchronize access to these resources, otherwise you will get garbage data. **You need to synchronize access everytime time you access shared resources on both devices.** In my case I needed to synchronize it twice, once on original Unity device when copying from Unity texture to shareable texture and then on my local device when using the local shared texture :

```cpp
IDXGIKeyedMutex* keyedMutex;
sharedTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIKeyedMutex), (void**)&keyedMutex);
keyedMutex->AcquireSync(0, INFINITE);
otherContext->CopyResource(dst, src);//use the correct context
keyedMutex->ReleaseSync(0);
```